# PHP media query width in php

Tags: html, css

I have a little script in php:

```
<section>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bilder";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $counter = 1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($counter == 1){
            echo "<img class='image' src='$row[bild_pfad]' alt='$row[bild_name]' style='$row[bild_werte]'>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<img class='image image-margin' src='$row[bild_pfad]' alt='$row[bild_name]' style='$row[bild_werte]'>";
        }
        if($counter == 6){
            $counter = 1;
        }
        else{
            $counter = $counter + 1;
        }
    } 
?>
</section>
```

This script create "many" images. The informations for the images are in a database. In the normal case the `<section></section>` is `925px` width. 1 image is `150px x 150px` big.

```
.image{
    object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    object-fit: cover; 
}
.image-margin{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

In the normal case are 6 pictures side by side, with a margin leftof 5px. That's the reason why I used `$counter` in the script, because one row consists of 6 pictures and the first picture don't need a margin left. Now i used some media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 924px) {
section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 770px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 770px) {
section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 615px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 615px) {
section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 460px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 460px) {
section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 305px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
}
```

Every media query class leaves the row shrink by 1 and the picture go in the next row. My problem: in the script have i set 6 pictures in a row, how can I customize that for the media queries? (for 5-, 4-, 3-, 2- pictures in one row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a counter variable to determine where margin should be.

Use the nth-child CSS selector to determine which images should have margin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Set your margins on the right and remove margin from the last image in a row.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 924px) {
/* Five images in each row */
section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 770px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
  section img{
     margin-right:5px;  
  }
  section img:nth-child(5n+5){
    margin-right:0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 770px) {
  /* Four images in each row */
section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 615px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
  section img:nth-child(4n+4){
    margin-right:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is the link of my page [Page](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/up/). What did i wrong?

Comment: In your PHP, forget all the $counter stuff - just echo out the img - you don't  need a special "image-margin" class. Then please read about the nth-child CSS selector, and you can accomplish your layout using that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my output file: `<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bilder";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<img class='image' src='$row[bild_pfad]' alt='$row[bild_name]' style='$row[bild_werte]'>";
    } 
?>`

Comment: Ok, did you try the nth-child selector?

Comment: I found a solution. I have to reset the old nth-child selector.